# Expressing in Cypher bidirectional edges and lack of edge

Tags: neo4j, cypher

how to express in Cypher:
1. Nodes are not connected.
2. Nodes are biderectionally connected.

When it comes it should look like:

```
MATCH (u)<-[r]->(v)
WHERE id(u) < id(v)
RETURN (u), [r], (v)
```

However it seems to not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "bidirectional edges"? In neo4j, all relationships have 1 and only 1 direction (but you can design most queries to ignore the direction, so that you can have logically bidirectional relationships). Do you want to find all node pairs connected by relationships pointing in both directions, or do you want something else?

Answer (score 0):

You will almost certainly want to add labels and search criteria to your nodes for efficiency but working off of your original example.

Nodes not connected

```
MATCH (u),(v)
WHERE u <> v
AND NOT (u)--(v)
RETURN u, v
```

Nodes are bidirectionally connected would be something like this

```
MATCH (u)-[r]->(v)
WHERE (u)<--(v)
RETURN u, r, v
```